# Projective dimension of quotient of a projective module.

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose P is a projective module and $Q\subset P$ is a submodule of P. Now I want to show projective dimension of the quotient module $pd(P/Q)$ satisfies the following $$ pd (P/Q)= pd (Q) +1$$ Now from a projective resolution of Q of length n, I can generate a projective resolution of length $n+1$ for the quotient, by just inserting P in the resolution. But I can't understand how to show this projective resolution is of minimal length.

Please help.

Comment: In general you can only have an inequality. As an example take $Q$ to be a direct summand of $P$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.